# How do the leaders' AI personalities work?

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

Montezuma and Tokugawa seem to be very prone to waging war on me, just as Gandhi is always very friendly, so I guess it's safe to assume that the leaders have different personalities. My question is:

- Does each leader have a pre-made
  AI personality script based on its
  historical counterpart? *(for example, Gandhi being a pacifist)*
- If not: Does
  the AI play to the leader's
  traits? *(for example, choosing to be
  on the offensive with Montezuma
  because of the Aggressive trait)*

Comment: I don't know the answer to the second one (whether leaders play to their traits all the time), but the first one is a resounding YES. You'll find yourself warring a LOT more with Alexander the great and Montezuma than you will Gandhi.

Comment: I read somewhere that the leaders in Alpha Centauri (also made by Sid Meier) had a scale from 1 to 10 of importance of three particular aspects:  aggressiveness, economy, technology.  I suppose Civilization 4 works roughly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have a pre-made AI personality script, that gives them their unique behaviour. To give an example, Catherine is the only leader that might declare war on you even if you have the best (Friendly) relationship, other leaders will never do this. She is the backstabber.

Of course this behaviour will also match their traits more or less, so Montezuma, Shaka or Napoleon are more likely to go into war (actually you will see them fighting most of the time), while Hatshepshut, Gandhi or even Mansa Musa will attack you quite rarely.